# How to add Launchpad repository to Fedora?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, software-installation, gnome, repository

On Fedora, custom software repositories [need to be added as a file](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/system-administrators-guide/package-management/DNF/#sec-Setting_repository_Options) to the [yum.repos.d](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/adding-or-removing-software-repositories-in-fedora/) directory.
But, which actual baseURL shall I add, when the software is hosted on launchpad?
Examples: [1](https://launchpad.net/gloobus-preview), [2](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8).

Answer (score 2):

To add a custom repository you actually need a repository with RPM packages, Launchpad doesn't offer option to build RPM packages, only DEB packages for Ubuntu or Debian via PPA repositories, so there isn't a way to make a repository from a Launchpad project (unless the project itself hosts a Fedora repository somewhere else than on Launchpad).

Gloobus used to be packaged in Fedora, but was removed and project looks dead (latest release is from 2009) so I don't thing there is any active repository for Fedora and I am not even sure you'd be able to build it from source because the package was removed from Fedora because it [failed to build](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1833964).

WebUpd8 is a PPA repository with collection of packages. Some of them are available in Fedora repositories, for the rest you'll need to search (or ask) specifically